# How can I decode data from google rtdn?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I use nestjs and I am trying to implement Google IAP.

Sends subscription data to the server through `google real-time developer notification`.

In this process, Google tells me to decode `base64` data.

In the case of ios, I was able to decode it easily through the `app-store-server-api` api.

In the case of Google, I wonder if there is such an api.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a buffer from the base64 string then parse to JSON, which will allow you to access the data from the RTDN:

As an example:

```
const b64string = body.message.data;

try {
    const bufferString = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64').toString();
    data = JSON.parse(bufferString);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR parse base64: ', err);
  }
```

You should be able to access the purchaseToken which can be used to validate the purchase with the android publisher API. You can use the Google Android Publisher npm package to access the API:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/androidpublisher

Example accessing subscription (you will need to set up auth and init the client first):

```
    const subscriptionResponse = await androidPublisherClient.purchases.subscriptionsv2.get({
      packageName: ANDROID_BUNDLE_ID,
      token: data.subscriptionNotification.purchaseToken
    });
```